How to link an acknowledgement email message (EmailMessage record) to Case when these 2 records are generated via a flow?
Here below more context :
We want to automatically create a new Case when a customer sends a reply to a closed Case.
So we created a flow that checks the status of the Parent Case the incoming EmailMessage is related to, and when the Status = Closed, we create a new Case with the information from the Parent Case the incoming EmailMessage is related to.
Our issue is here :
The Email Alert "TEST EMAIL TO CASE CLOSED", sending the acknowledgement message, is not linked to the newly created Case, which ID is retrieved using the "NewCaseId_text" variable, and the email message does not appear anywhere in our instance :


Do you have any idea about what may be wrong here ?
Thank you for your help.
